# Check multiple $_SESSION are empty

Tags: php, session, loops

I have multiple `$_SESSION` variables with different names (e.g `$_SESSION['blue'], _SESSION['purple'], _SESSION['cream'] etc...` is there any way I can use a loop to check which ones are empty and therefore ignore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) { 
    if (empty($value)) {
         // ignore 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `foreach loop`

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value)
{
  // This goes through the keys that exist.
}
```